# How are these methods allowing / causing data to be lost on disk?

Tags: java, persistence

I have a program that writes its settings and data out to disk every so often (15 seconds or so).

If the program is running and the computer is shut off abruptly -- for example, with the power being cut at the wall -- somehow all of my data files on disk are changed to empty files.

Here is my code, which I thought I designed to protect against this failure, but based on testing the failure still exists:

**SaveAllData** -- Called every so often, and also when JavaFX.Application.stop() is called.

```
public void saveAllData () {
    createNecessaryFolders();
    saveAlbumsAndTracks();
    saveSources();
    saveCurrentList();
    saveQueue();
    saveHistory();
    saveLibraryPlaylists();
    saveSettings();
    saveHotkeys();
}
```

**CreateNecessaryFolders**

```
private void createNecessaryFolders () {
    if ( !playlistsDirectory.exists() ) {
        boolean playlistDir = playlistsDirectory.mkdirs();
    }
}
```

**Save Functions -- they all look just like this**

```
public void saveCurrentList () {
    File tempCurrentFile = new File ( currentFile.toString() + ".temp" );
    try ( ObjectOutputStream currentListOut = new ObjectOutputStream( new FileOutputStream( tempCurrentFile ) ) ) {
        currentListOut.writeObject( player.getCurrentList().getState() );
        currentListOut.flush();
        currentListOut.close();

        Files.move( tempCurrentFile.toPath(), currentFile.toPath(), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING );

    } catch ( Exception e ) {
        LOGGER.warning( e.getClass().getCanonicalName() + ": Unable to save current list to disk, continuing." );
    }
}
```

[Github repository to commit where this problem exists. See Persister.java.](https://github.com/JoshuaD84/HypnosMusicPlayer/tree/d4745fed114c9e0f3e281f4d865ee0984f4590d9/src/net/joshuad/hypnos)

As I said, when the power is cut abruptly **all setting files saved by this method** are blanked. This makes particularly no sense to me, since they are called in sequence and I am making sure the file is written to disk and flushed before calling move().

Any idea how this could be happening? I thought by calling flush, close, then move, I would ensure that the data is written to disk before overwriting the old data. Somehow, this isn't the case, but I am clueless. Any suggestions?

Note: these files are **only** written to by these functions, and **only** read from by corresponding load() functions. There is no other access to the files any where else in my program.

Note 2: I am experiencing this on Ubuntu Linux 16.10. I have not tested it on other platforms yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `StandardCopyOption.ATOMIC_MOVE` to the `Files.move()` call solves the problem:

```
public void saveCurrentList () {
    File tempCurrentFile = new File ( currentFile.toString() + ".temp" );
    try ( ObjectOutputStream currentListOut = new ObjectOutputStream( new FileOutputStream( tempCurrentFile ) ) ) {
        currentListOut.writeObject( player.getCurrentList().getState() );
        currentListOut.flush();
        currentListOut.close();

        Files.move( tempCurrentFile.toPath(), currentFile.toPath(), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING, StandardCopyOption.ATOMIC_MOVE );

    } catch ( Exception e ) {
        LOGGER.warning( e.getClass().getCanonicalName() + ": Unable to save current list to disk, continuing." );
    }
}
```